# combination patent - do I need to specify type of a component (sensor)?

Tags: search

can I patent a machine that includes a motion sensor that has already patented. their are many types of motion sensors so can I use only "motion sensor" specific word in patent application or whether I need to specify a specific one.

Comment: If the machine can use any generic motion sensor, then you shouldn't have to specify. If the machine needs a particular kind, e.g. magnetic field sensor, not PIR sensor, then you should specify the type.

Comment: what if the particular sensor  (e.g.PIR sensor) has already patented so can I include that sensor in my patent application ?

Comment: in the Claim or in the Detailed Description?

Comment: if in my patent application machine includes a signal transfer through data cable can someone other can patent same machine that transfer signal through wifi or Bluetooth?

Comment: Claims are drafted from broader to narrower to checkmate  such probabilities. Broader terms e.g. means of communication (preferably defined in specification) may start with independent claim and particular com means in dependent claim is routine.

Answer (score 1):

Any element (e.g. motion sensor, means of communication and of interface between functional parts) which is well known in the industry field and performs routine function does not add "some thing more" to claimed invention and will raise judicial exception (abstract idea) if such an element is found in claims.

However, if a machine is 'novel' and 'non-obvious' and a particular element(like motion sensor, means of communication) helps to link functional steps of the claims and in combination with other elements of the machine achieves a novel result or prove to be a novel means for achieving any known result then the claims are likely to be found eligible for allowance.

Inclusion of generic computer or computer elements (e.g. memory, processor, CPU etc) and information technology in claims now faces a great hurdle in the form of judicial exception post 'Alice opinion' which is a supreme court (US) judgement. Whenever these elements are involved, the drafting of specification and claims become really tricky. If combination of claim elements conforms to judgement such as  Diehr, Bascom and SiRF Technology then a patent application has chance of being considered patent eligible. CAFC judgement in Thales Visionix  Inc vs US dtd 08 Mar 2017 is another recent judgement which patent applicants may find as favorable precedent.

Answer (score 0):

If a generic motion sensor enables your invention than that is sufficient. If a specific patented sensor is required than you need to specify that since your patent description must enable the invention. You can indeed obtain a patent that builds upon another patented device as long as your invention meets the standards for patentability. Namely it must be novel, non-obvious (contain an inventive element) and be useful.

That said, you must also consider freedom-to-operate. Just because you may obtain a patent, doesn't mean you automatically gain access to the previously patented device. You will still need to obtain permission to use it if it is essential to the functioning of your invention.

Comment: Also consider that patent rights only limit others in countries where they are issued and remain enforceable.  I could, in theory, freely make and sell a motion sensor in China if it's only patented in the USA.